# Magento Collection returns 10 records only

Tags: magento-enterprise

I am attempting to pull records from a table in Magento platform. It always returns only 10 records, no matter how many rows are in the table.

here is my function:

```
public function getWarrantyClaims(){
    $collection= Mage::getModel('blah/blah')->getCollection()
    ->addFieldToFilter('dealerid', array('in'=>Mage::helper('blah/blah')->getUserIds()));
    $collection->setOrder('ponumber','DESC');
    return $collection;
}
```

it returns 10 records (there is 13 in database table) Here is the results from

```
 echo $collection->load()->getSelect();
```

SELECT `main_table`.* FROM `blah` AS `main_table` WHERE (dealerid IN('6205', '7990')) ORDER BY ponumber DESC

If I add setPageSize(100); I still only get 10 records.

Comment: It could be that the collection was already instantiated before see this article: http://alanstorm.com/magento_collections

Comment: what happens if you try using the resource model directly `Mage::getResourceModel('blah/blah_collection')->addFieldToFilter('dealerid', array('in'=>Mage::helper('blah/blah')->getUserIds()))->load();`

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined method Blah_Blah_Model_Mysql4_Warrantyclaim::addFieldToFilter()

Comment: show config.xml.. lot of issue in models

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone else stumbles across this issue. From magento forums:

I was calling my the function like this:

```
protected function getMyCollection()
{
    if (is_null($this->_myCollection)) {
        $this->_myCollection = $this->getWarrantyClaims()
    }

    return $this->_myCollection;
}
```

Which then referenced to

```
public function getWarrantyClaims()
{
   $collection= Mage::getModel('blah/blah')->getCollection()
   ->addFieldToFilter('dealerid', array('in'=>Mage::helper('blah/blah')->getUserIds()));
   $collection->setOrder('ponumber','DESC');
   return $collection;
 }
```

But in function getMyCollection I had to modify the function to this:

```
protected function getMyCollection()
{
    if (is_null($this->_myCollection)) {
        $this->_myCollection = $this->getWarrantyClaims()
                    ->clear()
                    ->setPageSize(100)
                    ->load();
    }

    return $this->_myCollection;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi you issue in resource model.where you  have not call resource model.
check config.xml code..

```
 <global>
        <models>
            <blah>
                <class>Blah_Blah_Model_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>blah_mysql4</resourceModel>
            </blah>
            <blah_mysql4>
                <class>Blah_Blah_Model_Mysql4</class>
                <entities>
                    <blah>
                        <table>tablename</table>
                    </blah>
                </entities>
            </blah_mysql4>
        </models>
</global>
```

More details how to define ,declare check this
http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/custom_module_with_custom_database_table

Answer (score 1):

Recently i also face this problem... It 4 hours of debugging then i reach at final problem. When i debug this with pager block class then i found when pager initalize it have their default Available limit. And it always take index **0** of this array to show list of items, and array is `array{ 10=>10,20=>20,...... So on }`.

Then i finally found when you are setting collection then if you want to your custom list of items to show then you just need to set `$pager->setAvailbleLimit(array(12=>12, 30=>30......etc))`.

But write this just before y
When you are setting pager collection eg: just before 
 `$pager->setAvailableLimit`.

Hope this may help u, try to this thing as i mention if not solved then please bedug pager block. :)